# The preview render its not the same as the final render

Tags: rendering

[image]

Every time time I render, the preview render its not the same as the final render. You can see on the image, the preview render, show a lot shadow beyond the mountain and the final render its not the same.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: From the outliner, check to make sure all lamps are marked as visible in both the viewport and the renderview. Also, are you using renderlayers?

Comment: I found some lightsource was hidden,so i turned on. Now its everything is right. Thanks for the tips Guy.

Answer (score 2):

Delete Hidden Lights Because Blender renders even unchecked  lights